# Problemas al mostrar datos correctamente en un datatable

Tags: javascript, php

Me gustaría dar formato a una tabla. El problema de la tabla es que los datos no se muestran correctamente. Ejemplo: PESO = 20,000.00 me muestra un 20,000 faltando .00 ,SACOS me muestra 1,000.00 - restar los .00 .Los pequeños inconvenientes están comentados en el código.
Investigue pero en esto me quede estancando, espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

```js
var tbl_dtproducto;
function Listar_DTProducto(id){
    tbl_dtproducto = $("#tabla_dtproducto").DataTable({
        "ordering":false,
        "bLengthChange":true,
        "searching": { "regex": false },
        "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
        "pageLength": 10,
        "destroy":true,
        "async": false ,
        "processing": true,
        ///////Datatable ocultar MOST,REG,TOT
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "sDom": 't',

        "ajax":{
            "url":"../controller/datos/controlador_listar_dtproducto.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                id:id
            }
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"PRODUCTO"},
            {"data":"EMPAQUE"},
            {"data":"PRESENTACION"},
            {"data":"PESO",
             render: DataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 3)// me muestra 20,000 - falta 00
            },
            {"data":"SACOS",
            render: DataTable.render.number(',','.',3)//me muestra 1,000.00 - restar los 00
            },
            {"data":"P_BASE"},
            {"data":"T_BASE",
            render: DataTable.render.number('.',',',3)// me muestra 58,300 me muestra - falta 00
            },
            {"data":"P_COSTO"},
            {"data":"T_COSTO",
            render: DataTable.render.number('.',',',3)// me muestra 61,280- falta 00
            },
            {"data":"P_VENTA"},
            {"data":"T_VENTA",
            render: DataTable.render.number('.',',',3)// me muestra 61,200 - falta 00
             },
            ],
            "language":idioma_espanol,
            select: true,
            deferRender: true,
            scroller:true,
            scrollColapse:true,
            scrollY: 110,
            scrollX: true
                });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `number: function ( thousands, decimal, precision, prefix, postfix )`

Comment: disculpa, por la pregunta pero como seria implementar lo que comentas?

Comment: Eso que he pegado es la sintaxis que he encontrado en el código fuente de `number`... Donde el primer parámetro representa el separador de los miles (thousands), el segundo parámetro representa el separador de los decimales (decimal), y el tercer parámetro la cantidad de decimales que quieres mostrar (precision)... los otros dos no hace falta que los uses a menos que quieras poner un prefijo (como un signo de dolar) o un sufijo (como el simbolo del euro).  Como no se que usais para los PESOS por eso solo te he puesto la sintaxis, para que la apliques como te convenga.

Comment: Y no es que tenga que enseñarte como implementarlo, ya lo estas haciendo pues la estas usando cuando escribes esto: `DataTable.render.number( '.', ',', 3)// me muestra 20,000` o cuando escribes esto: `DataTable.render.number(',','.',3)//me muestra 1,000.00`.  Ahora te toca entender lo que acabo de explicar y aplicarlo correctamente para que muestre lo que necesitas mostrar tal como lo quieres mostrar (que eso ya es cosa tuya, pues repito, no se la sintaxis que usais en vuestra ubicación, si comas o puntos para los miles, etc)